# finfo_file returning false for some mp4 files

Tags: php, mime-types, mp4

I use the following code to get the type of file being uploaded:

```
            $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
            $mime_type=finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']);
            finfo_close($finfo);
```

This works fine for most videos. But for some mp4 it returns false. Two mp4 videos I downloaded from vimeo return false but another 2 sample mp4 videos return video/mp4.

Any ideas?

Comment: fileinfo doesn't scan the ENTIRE file, just a chunk of the headers to try and guess what the content is. if the mp4's been wrapped inside other stuff, fileinfo will give up with an unknown type.

Comment: Thank you. Actually it was a problen with the file exceeding the upload_max_filesize limit.